# Making a column a map in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Say I have this db:

```
{"customerIdMarketplace": 1234, itemId: "rocks"}  
{"customerIdMarketplace": 1234, itemId: "pebbles"}  
{"customerIdMarketplace": 1234, itemId: "papers"}  
{"customerIdMarketplace": 2345, itemId: "socks"}  
{"customerIdMarketplace": 2345, itemId: "shoes"}
```

I want to create this dataset:

```
{"customerIdMarketplace": 1234, items: [{"id": "rocks"}, {"id":"pebbles"}, {"id": "papers"}]}  
{"customerIdMarketplace": 2345, items: [{"id": "socks"}, {id: "shoes"}]}
```

The goal is to group all the items into a list if the `customerIdMarketplace` is the same, and represent it as a map in a sense where each item has the key `id`.

What I have so far is:

```
db.select("customerIdMarketplace", "itemId")
  .groupby("customerIdMarketplace")
  .agg(collect_set("itemId").as("items"))
```

But this doesn't make the `id` key. How can I do this correctly?

Comment: I think you need something like `.map { value  => ("id", value) }` after agg

Answer (score 1):

The `collect_set` call is fine, but you need to make a json object for each `itemId`, right? so you need to create a map fist. This is the code snippet on spark shell:

```scala
// customId is short for customerIdMarketplace
scala> db.select("customerId", "itemId").groupBy("customerId").agg(collect_set(to_json(map(lit("id"), col("itemId"))))).show(false)
+----------+---------------------------------------------------+
|customerId|collect_set(to_json(map(id, itemId)))              |
+----------+---------------------------------------------------+
|1234      |[{"id":"papers"}, {"id":"pebbles"}, {"id":"rocks"}]|
|2345      |[{"id":"shoes"}, {"id":"socks"}]                   |
+----------+---------------------------------------------------+
```

If you don't need json, just use map:

```scala
scala> mp.select("customerId", "itemId").groupBy("customerId").agg(collect_list(map(lit("id"), col("itemId")))).show(false)
+----------+------------------------------------------------+
|customerId|collect_list(map(id, itemId))                   |
+----------+------------------------------------------------+
|1234      |[[id -> rocks], [id -> pebbles], [id -> papers]]|
|2345      |[[id -> socks], [id -> shoes]]                  |
+----------+------------------------------------------------+
```

Now if you want to store them as map instead of json, you cannot use `collect_set` method, since comparing maps (to check for double insertion) is not supported in spark.

Comment: Few things to mention, “mp” in the second expression is “db”, I forgot to rename is, and also I forgot to give an alias to “collect” thing.